# Load text column from mysql to php as HTML format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a big MYSQL DB that i store lyrics.
my text column has lyrics like this :

**i do not have any \n or br tag in my column.**

row1 =

aaaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbb

cccccccc

row2 =

xxxxxxx

yyyyyy

zzzzzz

and ...

when i import from MYSQL to PHP it shows

- xxxxxx yyyyyy zzzzzz
- aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc

How can i load as same as text column format in MYSQL ?!

```
                  <span lang="fa"><?=$row['text'];?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your data in [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
<span lang="fa"><?= nl2br($row['text']); ?></span>
```

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

Comment: I stored many data as palin text in my db. i test this code on my php and does not work.

Comment: it skip break , i have a solution that php does not skip breaks.